# PrestaShop: tax calculation wrong because of wrong country id

Tags: php, export, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, tax

I have a problem by creating an XML Export for product data.
The PrestaShop Version I'm using is 1.7.3.1

**our setup:**
One Site xyz.com where we have different routes for our countries .com/de and .com/at and .com/it

**our need:**
We need a XML File which all products and the writh prices with the right tax calcualation (it's different in de/at and it).
As I call the script via the browser and I'm not logged in.
So I have no country id and the geotagging say I'm from Austria and get for ALL products the tax rate from Austria - Unfortunately it's wrong.

**what I tried** (one of many things I tried)
When I call the script for Italy I set the global context country to IT.

```php
switch ( $shop ) {
    case "DE":
        /* .... */
        break;
    case "AT":
        /* .... */
        break;
    case "IT":
        $id_shop = 6;
        $id_lang = 4;
        $replace = '.com/it/';
        $country = Country::getCountriesByZoneId(10, 4);
        Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_SHOP, 6);
        Context::getContext()->shop->id = 6;
        Context::getContext()->country = $country;
        break;
}
```

but the tax calculation is wrong and I get always the same price for each country.

Do you have ideas, how I could achieve the different tax rates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The solutuion was instead of

```php
$country = Country::getCountriesByZoneId(10, 4);
Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_SHOP, 6);
Context::getContext()->shop->id = 6;
Context::getContext()->country = $country;
```

I use this now

```php
Context::getContext()->country = new Country(/*Enter country ID here*/);
```